# How can I authenticate with tokens in django rest framework

Tags: django, angularjs, rest, django-rest-framework

I'm learning to use token to authenticate users in angular.js front end.

I'm using below package(JSON Web Token Authentication support for Django REST Framework)

https://github.com/GetBlimp/django-rest-framework-jwt

I have implemented all settings and sample curl request is working fine.

Now I have login page with angularjs which posts to rest endpoint as shown in below code:

```
$http
  .post('/api-token-auth/', {email: $scope.account.email, password: $scope.account.password})
  .then(function(response) {
    // assumes if ok, response is an object with some data, if not, a string with error
    // customize according to your api
    if ( !response.account ) {
      $scope.authMsg = 'Incorrect credentials.';
    }else{
      $state.go('dashboard');
    }
  }, function(x) {
    $scope.authMsg = 'Server Request Error';
  });
```

Now when I post email and password then in the response I get successful token like this

```
{"token":"eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InNhbXBsZUBzYW1wbGUuY29tIiwidXNlcl9pZCI6MSwiZW1haWwiOiJzYW1wbGVAc2FtcGxlLmNvbSIsImV4cCI6MTQyOTA5NjM5N30
.w0XV1kArTyZY9iCPyr2LmRzToD9iOgYlMVCoXmdOJ1A"}
```

Now as I don't know much about tokens, I want to know what should I do next? I mean after getting token how can I log the user in and put that user in some `userObject` in angular.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must pass the token as you Authorization header in every request where you access logged in content. You can do this by using $https default headers.

```
   $http
   .post('/api-token-auth/', {email: $scope.account.email, password: $scope.account.password})
   .then(function(response) {
    ...
    } else {
        localStorage.setItem('myApp.token',response.token);
        $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + response.token
        $state.go('dashboard');
    }
    ...
```

You should also save this value in localstorage and set the default header in you apps run, so that when a user comes back yo your page they are already logged in. Like this:

```
angular.module('myApp').run(function($http) {
    $http.defaults.headers.common.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem('myApp.token')
});
```

Comment: thanks.  I could not get ur second part where u say i need to put default header in app run . how can i do that. also if use ur line does it mean that next time user don't need to login if they access authenticated iurl

Comment: I've updated the answer now, set the token in localstorage when logging in. The run block will fire when your app starts and fetch the token from localstorage and use that as defualt header, then your users shouldnt have to log in anymore! :)

Comment: thanks for that. Is there any way to also get the username , userid etc along with token in response so that i can update the angular User object

Answer (score 0):

If you receive a token as a response, it means that the user is already logged in.

To use the token, you should add it as an http header for subsequent requests.

```
Authorization: JWT <your_token>
```